# Opening new pseudo-terminal device file in macOS with swift

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to keep a shell (`bash`/`zsh`/`etc`) running by using Process from the Foundation library.

I know how to use Pipe for standard input/output/error for other command line executables but it seems like the shell programs require that the standard input/output/error file be a terminal device file.

It looks like these are the files called `/dev/ttys<3 digit number>` which are created for every new shell instance.
How can I create these files myself and use them in swift?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

So this turned out to be a lot easier than I thought it would be.
Here are the steps needed to create a pair of master and slave pseudo-terminal `FileHandle` objects:

1. Import the `Darwin` module.
2. Call on `posix_openpt(int oflag)` to get a file descriptor for an available master pseudo-terminal device.
3. Call on `grantpt(int filedes)` to establish ownership of corresponding slave pseudo-terminal device.
4. Call on `unlockpt(int filedes)` to unlock the slave pseudo-terminal device.
5. Call on `ptsname(int filedes)` to get path to slave pseudo-terminal device.
6. Create `FileHandle` objects using the file descriptor from step 2 and path from step 5.

In steps 3 - 5 `filedes` is the file descriptor returned by the call to `posix_openpt(int oflag)` from step 1. 
Use `O_RDRW` for the `oflag` parameter in step 1 for read-write permissions on the master pseudo-terminal device file.

Example code where we keep a `bash` session alive and have it run the `tty` command:

```
import Foundation
import Darwin

class A: NSObject {
    var task: Process?
    var slaveFile: FileHandle?
    var masterFile: FileHandle?

    override init() {
        self.task = Process()
        var masterFD: Int32 = 0
        masterFD = posix_openpt(O_RDWR)
        grantpt(masterFD)
        unlockpt(masterFD)
        self.masterFile = FileHandle.init(fileDescriptor: masterFD)
        let slavePath = String.init(cString: ptsname(masterFD))
        self.slaveFile = FileHandle.init(forUpdatingAtPath: slavePath)
        self.task!.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/bash")
        self.task!.arguments = ["-i"]
        self.task!.standardOutput = slaveFile
        self.task!.standardInput = slaveFile
        self.task!.standardError = slaveFile
    }

    func run() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }
            do {
                try self.task!.run()
            } catch {
                print("Something went wrong.\n")
            }
        }
        let data = self.masterFile!.availableData
        let strData = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        print("Output: "+strData)
        self.masterFile!.write("tty\u{0D}".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        sleep(1)
        let data1 = self.masterFile!.availableData
        let strData1 = String(data: data1, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        print("Output: "+strData1)
    }
}

let a = A()
a.run()
```

Answer (score -1):

An even simpler answer that is Playground friendly.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation
import Darwin

// use socat to create psudo echo device
// socat -d -d -x pty,raw,nonblock,ispeed=115200,echo=0,link=/dev/ttys000 EXEC:/bin/cat

print("Started:\n")
var masterFile: FileHandle?

var masterFD: Int32 = 0
masterFD = open("/dev/ttys000",O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)
grantpt(masterFD)
unlockpt(masterFD)
masterFile = FileHandle.init(fileDescriptor: masterFD)

masterFile!.write("tty\u{0D}".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
sleep(1)

let data1 = masterFile!.availableData
let strData1 = String(data: data1, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
print("Output: "+strData1)
```